# How to subtract ten minutes from a time picked from time picker?

Tags: ios, swift, datetimepicker

I have a time picker in which the user picks the time and I am sending a notification to user ten minutes before or after the time user picked.Suppose if the user picks time as 11:00 AM then I want the notification to trigger at 10:55 AM. I am unable to subtract and add ten minutes to the time. As I am new to this Please help..I have spent a lot of time on it still not able to solve this. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could subtract minutes using the `Calendar` :

`Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -10, to: yourDate)`

Answer (score 0):

Use Calendar of iOS.

> let beforeThreeMinutes = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -3, to: datePicker.date)

Comment: thank you for your answer...just have one query if have time like this 11:59AM how can I subtract 10 minutes from here.

Comment: Date from DatePicker can be in any format, that should not cause any issue.